# Can isotropy (or anisotropy) be expressed in terms of intervals ($s^2$) between pairs of events?

Tags: mathematical-physics, spacetime, metric-space

Considering a set $\mathcal S$ of events and given the values of intervals $s^2[~P, Q~] \in \mathbb R$
for all pairs of events $P, Q \in \mathcal S$ (up to a common non-zero scale factor):
how can conditions be expressed for whether $\mathcal S$ is "isotropic"?,

and in particular:
such that these conditions are equivalent to the definition of an [*isotropic manifold*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_manifold)
in case that set $\mathcal S$ constitutes a manifold.